# Appium 2.0: Not able to save log-> EBUSY: resource busy or locked

Tags: appium-java

Appium Java-Client: v8.5.1
Appium server version: v2.1.3
Desktop OS/version: Windows 10
Node.js version: v18.18.0

I am starting and stopping the Appium server programmatically which is working properly and I am able to view the Appium logs in console. But when tried to save this log into fil; at that time I am getting error EBUSY: resource busy or locked. Both folder Logs and file Server.logs are present.

```
private static AppiumDriverLocalService appiumDriverLocalService;

private static AppiumDriverLocalService getAppiumDriverService() {
        return AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
                .usingPort(DEFAULT_APPIUM_SERVER_PORT)
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.BASEPATH, "/wd/hub/")
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "info:debug")
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.USE_DRIVERS, "UiAutomator2")
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.ALLOW_INSECURE, "adb_shell")
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.RELAXED_SECURITY)
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.USE_PLUGINS, "images")
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE)
                .withLogFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Logs" + File.separator + "Server.logs")));
    }
```

Added .withLogFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "Logs" + File.separator + "Server.logs")));
This prints logs in console, but not in file.

I want this to be saved in **Server.logs**

```
Tried to attach logging to file 'D:\Automation-Framework\Generic\generic\Logs\Server.logs' but an error occurred:** EBUSY: resource busy or locked**, unlink 'D:\Automation-Framework\Generic\generic\Logs\Server.logs'
[Appium] Attempting to load plugin images...
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v2.1.3
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium] { address: '127.0.0.1',
[Appium]   allowInsecure: [ 'adb_shell' ],
[Appium]   basePath: '/wd/hub/',
[Appium]   loglevel: 'info:debug',
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true,
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true,
[Appium]   useDrivers: [ 'UiAutomator2' ],
[Appium]   usePlugins: [ 'images' ] }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
[Appium] Available drivers:
[Appium]   - uiautomator2@2.29.9 (automationName 'UiAutomator2')
[Appium]   - espresso@2.25.7 (automationName 'Espresso')
[Appium] Available plugins:
[Appium]   - images@2.1.4 (ACTIVE)
[Appium]   - element-wait@2.0.3
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status
[HTTP] {}
[AppiumDriver@c5c5] Plugins which can handle cmd 'getStatus': images
[AppiumDriver@c5c5] Plugin images is now handling cmd 'getStatus'
[AppiumDriver@c5c5] Executing default handling behavior for command 'getStatus'
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 6 ms - 110
[HTTP]
```